# How to select preselect value in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have a task to develop a spinner base application which is relating to database. When I first create the application it selects the value from the spinner. After that, I have to fetch that value as a select value in a spinner  I search for it a lot but I can't found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            // this gets the item from adapter: parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
            textView.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have tryed with the given code but i cant found it properly the result of it. i cant get any value from it. please help me i am very afraid about it.